# How to use XSLT to create distinct values

Tags: xslt

I have XML like this:

```
<items>
  <item>
    <products>
      <product>laptop</product>
      <product>charger</product>
    </products>
  </item>
  <item>
    <products>
      <product>laptop</product>
      <product>headphones</product>  
    </products>  
  </item>
</items>
```

I want it to output like

```
laptop
charger
headphones
```

I was trying to use `distinct-values()` but I guess i m doing something wrong. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this using `distinct-values()`? Thanks.

```
<xsl:template match="/">            
  <xsl:for-each select="//products/product/text()">
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(.)"/>
    </li>               
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

but its giving me output like this:

```
<li>laptop</li>
<li>charger</li>
<li>laptop></li>
<li>headphones</li>
```

Comment: Might be worth looking at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813286/xslt-select-distinct-but-slightly-different-to-other-examples

Answer (score 57, accepted):

An **XSLT 1.0** solution that uses `key` and the `generate-id()` function to get distinct values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet
   version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="product" match="/items/item/products/product/text()" use="." />

<xsl:template match="/">

  <xsl:for-each select="/items/item/products/product/text()[generate-id()
                                       = generate-id(key('product',.)[1])]">
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </li>
  </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is working perfectly _only_ for finding distinct elements under entire / namespace. If the goal is to find distincts under cretain subtrees like in <warehouse name="a"><items...><warehouse name="b"> then the global key approach is no longer valid...

Comment: @R. Simac - you can adjust the match expression for the key to match a different set of items.

Comment: @Mads, I was thinking of being unable to set the key match 'dynamically'. I don't know how to use/instruct key to match only the distinct items under warehouse X...

Comment: I needed to output also a sibling of the <product>. This solution did not work for me, and the one with `preceding` did.

Answer (score 59):

Here's an **XSLT 1.0** solution that I've used in the past, I think it's more succinct (and readable) than using the `generate-id()` function.

```
  <xsl:template match="/">           
    <ul> 
      <xsl:for-each select="//products/product[not(.=preceding::*)]">
        <li>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </li>   
      </xsl:for-each>            
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
```

Returns:

```
<ul xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <li>laptop</li>
  <li>charger</li>
  <li>headphones</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: While appreciating the answer above which is completely applicable for the original case, just wanted to note the above approach is not applicable for slightly more complex schema, where each product has it's own elements, for example: <products>
<product><name>charger</name></product>
<product><name>laptop</name></product>
... I was not able to find distinct names for such layout, maybe reaching xslt1.0 limitations here...

Comment: Really @R.Simac? The following xpath should give you the products, with the first instance of a name (if this is what you want?)... `//product[not(./name=preceding::*/name)]`. I believe that it may not work for all scenarios, perhaps you can you provide an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: @NickG ... it was one of these 'it does not work for me (tm)' situations... For example, your suggestion does not produce any output for following xml (sorry for ugly formatting, time constrained):

<items>
  <item>
    <products>
      <product><name>laptop</name></product>
      <product><name>charger</name></product>
    </products>
  </item>
  <item>
    <products>
      <product><name>laptop</name></product>
      <product><name>headphones</name></product>
      <product><name>charger</name></product>  
    </products>  
  </item>
</items>

Comment: @NickG I stand corrected. It does work. It was my xsl processor setup (eclipse) that is to blame along with me doing heavy multitasking. Also thanks for the online xslt processor site link, did not know about it...

Comment: @NickG, it appears I finnally pinpointed the actual problem case that is/was bothering me. It has to do with what I refer to as non-continuous element lists (there may be better name for it). At any rate, the attached sample is definitely not working. Any comments appreciated. http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/lB8i4j/5

Comment: +1. I needed to output also a sibling of the <product>. This solution worked for me, and the one with `generate-id()` did not

Comment: Not a good solution - read here why: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: @michael.hor257k - "Not a good solution" - that's your opinion, but you should probably elaborate. The extra developer effort (time and cost) to recall, understand and write the `<xsl:key` method, will surely negate the extra inefficient cpu cycles impacting your end customer... the real question is, why are you using `xsl1` to find distinct values in large datasets in your high performance environment?

Comment: Jeni Tennison already elaborated, many years ago. Muenchian grouping is a well-established design pattern in XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 21):

You don't want "output (distinct-values)", but rather "for-each (distinct-values)":

```
<xsl:template match="/">              
  <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(/items/item/products/product/text())">
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </li>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Tomalak xslt 2.0 is not supported by browser...just came to knw...while testing ...any way to do it without xslt 2.0

Comment: @AB - I've added an XSLT 1.0 solution

Answer (score 16):

I came to this problem while working with a Sitecore XSL rendering.  Both the approach that used key() and the approach that used the preceding axis performed very slowly.  I ended up using a method similar to key() but that did not require using key().  It performs very quickly.

```
<xsl:variable name="prods" select="items/item/products/product" />
<xsl:for-each select="$prods">
  <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id($prods[. = current()][1])">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <br />
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: This worked for me. It was nice to be able to keep things tightly encapsulated within the stylesheet.  Adding <xsl:apply-templates select = ".." mode="summary"/>  in place of the value-of allowed me to apply the template to only the specific node.

Answer (score 10):

`distinct-values(//product/text())`

Comment: @Tomalak, "exponential"? No, only *linear* in the number of element nodes and any-type leaf nodes in the XML document.

Comment: I cannot get this to work, my compiler(eclipse) is complaining that this is invalid XPath.

Comment: @Nicholas This is for XSLT 2.0 but you are working with an XSLT 1.0 processor. You have to use an `<xsl:key>`, like the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2293626/18771) does.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can do what you want with XSLT 1.0 without `generate-id()` and `key()` functions.

Here is Microsoft-specific solution (.NET's [XslCompiledTransform](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform) class, or [MSXSLT.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21714) or Microsoft platfocm COM-objects).

It is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2272522/1191799). You can copy sorted node set to variable (`$sorted-products` in the stylesheet below), then convert it to node-set using `ms:node-set` function. Then you able `for-each` second time upon sorted node-set:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="ms">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="sorted-products">
        <xsl:for-each select="//products/product">
            <xsl:sort select="text()" />

            <xsl:copy-of select=".|@*" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="products" select="ms:node-set($sorted-products)/product" />

    <xsl:for-each select="$products">
      <xsl:variable name='previous-position' select="position()-1" />

      <xsl:if test="normalize-space($products[$previous-position]) != normalize-space(./text())">
        <li>
          <xsl:value-of select="./text()" />
        </li>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output:

```
<li>charger</li>
<li>headphones</li>
<li>laptop</li>
```

You can try it out [in online playground](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq6u).

Comment: Not a good solution - read here why: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html