# Need help on xsl/xquery desired ouput

Tags: xslt, xquery

My requirement is like below:

Input :-

```
<Root>
<Name>abc</Name>
<Name>def</Name>
<Name>abc</Name>
<Name>abc</Name>
<Name>def</Name>
<Name>def</Name>
</Root>
```

Output:-  I need to make xml of Name element who's value don't be repititive

```
<Root>
<Name>abc</Name>
<Name>def</Name>  
</Root>
```

We can use xsl or xquery anything...
Please help me on the same...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291567/how-to-use-xslt-to-create-distinct-values

Comment: Thanks Magicianred...

Comment: Hi, It worked when there is no namespace defined with xml. But In real case, xml will contains namespace  like below:-             <Root xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/abc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Name>abc</Name>
<Name>def</Name>
<Name>abc</Name>
<Name>abc</Name>
<Name>def</Name>
<Name>def</Name>
</Root>

Comment: You have tried to add namespace to xsl:for-each? <xsl:for-each select="xsi:Root/Name">?

Comment: hey tried with localname convention. It worked.. thanks alot for your super quick help...

Comment: Thanks to @Mads Hansen in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291567/how-to-use-xslt-to-create-distinct-values

Enjoy your code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0, use

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="/*/Name" group-by=".">
  <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

In XQuery 1.0 use

```
for $n in distinct-values(/*/Name)
return <Name>{$n}</Name>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @michael-kay's excellent answer, if you have XQuery 3.0 then you could use:

```
distinct-values(/*/Name) ! <Name>{.}</Name>
```

The `!` is the *Simple Map Operator*, which IMHO can be nicer for such simple one-line transformation cases than a `for`.