# How to increment variable by 1 in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

Consider a case I have to get the count of passed students, he is considered passed if he passes all the exams.

```
<testResults version="1.2">
<student test="1" pass="true" name="A"></student>
<student test="2" pass="true" name="A"></student>
<student test="1" pass="false" name="B"></student>
<student test="2" pass="true" name="B"></student>
<student test="1" pass="false" name="C"></student>
<student test="2" pass="false" name="C"></student>
<student test="1" pass="true" name="D"></student>
<student test="2" pass="true" name="D"></student>
</testResults>
```

I want to get the count of students who passed all subjects. How do I do that?
I got a method where I iterate through all the students and display who passed all but how do I get the count of all students.

I'm using ,

```
<xsl:for-each select="/testResults/student/[not(@name = preceding::*/@name)]">
<xsl:variable name="allFailureCount" select="count(/testResults/*[attribute::pass='false'][@tn = current()/@name])" />
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$allFailureCount &gt; 0"></xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show your current method that gets the students who passed? Thanks

Comment: The simple answer is that you don't. In XSLT you can't change the value of a variable, you can set it once and that's it. (Yes, I know this sounds weird at first.) If you want to count something, you just call the `count()` XPath function.

Comment: Hey @biziclop How would you use the XPath count function for that case?

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0, or just XSLT 1.0?

Comment: XSLT 2.0 is also available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here is a count of the "distinct" of student names, for students who have passed all their exams. It would probably help if you defined a key to look up the tests

```
<xsl:key name="students" match="student" use="@name" />
```

Then, to get the distinct list of passing students, you can use `distinct-values` in XSLT 2.0

```
distinct-values(testResults/student[not(key('students', @name)/@pass='false')]/@name)
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:key name="students" match="student" use="@name" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="passedStudents" select="distinct-values(testResults/student[not(key('students', @name)/@pass='false')]/@name)" />

      <xsl:for-each select="$passedStudents">
          <xsl:text>Student </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="." /><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:text>Total </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="count($passedStudents)" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <result>
         <xsl:variable name="prods" select="testResults/student/name" />
         <xsl:for-each select="$prods">
            <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id($prods[. = current()][1])">
               <xsl:if test="count(/testResults/student[@pass ='true' and name=current()]) = 2">
                  <name>
                     <xsl:value-of select="." />
                  </name>
               </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </result>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<result>
   <name>A</name>
   <name>D</name>
</result>
```

First it constructs list of unique names using approach from [How to use XSLT to create distinct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291567/how-to-use-xslt-to-create-distinct-values) - and then counts number of nodes that match 2 conditions - pass is true and name is equal current unique name. If count is equal to the number of tests (2 - I set it hard-coded) - the name is added to the output.

EDIT

To count names - you can store them into temp var and then use simple count

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="prods" select="testResults/student/name" />
      <xsl:variable name="passOne">
         <xsl:for-each select="$prods">
            <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id($prods[. = current()][1])">
               <xsl:if test="count(/testResults/student[@pass ='true' and name=current()]) = 2">
                  <name>
                     <xsl:value-of select="." />
                  </name>
               </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="count($passOne/name)" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, @artemy-vysotsky I actually wanted the count of those found, I have a similar approach as of yours! but, the question was to increment a variable value so that I can count them. Any other method to get the count is also fine.

Comment: Added possibility to count found names